# Facebook Graph API call returns false

Tags: php, json, facebook, facebook-graph-api, curl

I'm an amateur programmer trying to fetch my facebook page likes for my webpage since I do not want facebooks standard plugin. After a lot of research and testing I found out the right call to make which is:

> https://graph.facebook.com/{PAGE_ID}?access_token={APP_ID}|{APP_SECRET}&fields=fan_count

Using this in my web browser it works great and I get the fan count in json.

My problem is when I try to make this call using either cURL or file_get_contents inside a php script I dont seem to get anything back. After doing a var_dump I get bool(false) back. And after doing print_r I get nothing.

Is facebook somehow blocking my calls or what could be wrong? I have tried multiple ways I found online and none works. This is one of the examples:

```
<?php
    $json_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/XXXXXXXXXXX?access_token=XXXXXXXXXXXXX&fields=fan_count";
    $json = file_get_contents($json_url);
    $json = json_decode($json, true);

    print_r($json);

    echo "Number of likes : ". $json[0]->fan_count;
?>
```

This is another:

```
<?php
     $ch = curl_init("https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/XXXXXXXXXXXXX?access_token=XXXXXXXXXXXX&fields=fan_count");
     curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, false );
     curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true );
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.0; en-US; rv:1.7.12) Gecko/20050915 Firefox/1.0.7");
     curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false );
     curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
     $data = curl_exec( $ch );
     echo $data;
?>
```

The problem seem to be right after the graph call. Can't figure out why, all help will be appreciated :) Thanks!

Comment: What does file_get_contents return?

Comment: It returns nothing when I echo it and if I do a var_dump I get bool(false)

Comment: is facebook somehow blocking those calls because it works if I use "fql". but since they going to end it 7 august I want to do this with the graph api.
http://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?format=json&query=select+fan_count+from+page+where+page_id%3D{FACEBOOK_ID}